# MS Project - How to print the right Gantt diagram from custom view?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I'm using MS Project 2010 with a custom view that is showing baseline start/finish as well as start/finish fields of the tasks. I have modified the Gantt chart on the right hand side by cutting all rows in the "bar styles" list and inserting just bars for baseline tasks, baseline summary tasks and baseline milestones - this is showed correctly in my view.
The problem now is that when I want to print this view, it prints the start/finish dates of the tasks as well as dependency lines - not the baseline tasks.

How can I fix this? I want to print just the baseline bars without dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have deleted all the bars with the exception of the Baseline Bars, you should not be seeing dependency lines nor start and finish dates.  When you attempt to print, have you removed the modifications you made?

If I follow your steps, I don't see anything except the baseline bars.  My suggestion:

**Make your modified view a new view.**

1. Open the modified view.
2. Click the Gantt Chart drop down on the View Ribbon and select "Save
   View".  Give it a new name.

Does it appear correctly?
Does it print correctly?

**Re-set the Gantt chart view to default**

1. Re-apply the Gantt chart view
2. Click the Gantt Chart drop down on the View Ribbon and select "Reset to default".

When you want to print - switch to your view and print.  When done printing, switch back to the Gantt chart view.